# sed: change case of text enclosed within backticks

Tags: sql, sed

I'm writing a `bash` script to automatically perform some changes to `SQL` files. My problem is: how can I use `sed` to convert `CamelCase` text to `snake_case` ONLY where it's enclosed within backticks?

e.g. a line like the following:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo) VALUES (120, "YouTube video", "Linux and macOS");
```

should become:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_one, column_two) VALUES (120, "YouTube video", "Linux and macOS");
```

The following expression

```
sed -i -r 's/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/\1_\L\2/g' filename.sql
```

performs the first part of the desired job (text can eventually be easily turned to lowercase using `` sed -i 's/`[^`]*`/\L\0/g' filename.sql ``) but I need to limit its scope just to those parts enclosed within backticks (i.e. table and column names) leaving anything else untouched. How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't seen the backticks ?

So, with this input:

```
INSERT INTO `TableName (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo)` VALUES (120, "YouTube video", "Linux and macOS");
```

You can try this sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/(`.+)([a-z])([A-Z])([^`]+`)/\1\2_\L\3\4/;tA'
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped very much!

Comment: To get my job done I simply changed [a-z] to [a-z0-9] and [A-Z] to [A-Z0-9] to match numeric characters as well. Now it works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
 sed -E 's/(`[^`]*)([A-Z])([^`]*`)/\L\1\L_\2\3/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Perl – here is a *general-use* alternative – one which can handle multi-line files, multi-hump CamelCase, and will properly ignore strings (`"|'`) and SQL statements:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/(?<!\x22|\x27)([A-Z][a-z0-9]++)(?!\s|,|\))/\L\1_/g; s/(_)+([A-Z])?/\L\1\2/g' file
```